# Android java AsyncTask wait onPostExecute return method

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, callback, async-await

I wrote the following code, I'm looking for a way to make an http call, process the data and let me return the result.

The problem being an async operation, when I do `html.getTi()`, gives me no value because the operation is still running and I'm faster.

I tried to use: `synchronized (this) {..`
of java but it does not seem to work.

I thought about using a wait loop:

`while(html.getFlg ()! = false);`

but it takes too many resources and hangs.

I was thinking of using `callbacks` or `promises`, but I do not know if it's the right way.

Some advice?

Main.java

```
Html html = new Html().execute("...");
html.getTi();//return element ArrayList<ListItem>
```

Html.java

```
public class Html extends Activity {

    ArrayList<ListItem> listItemList = new ArrayList<ListItem>();

    public Html execute(String str) {
        new Http().execute(str);
        return this;
    }

    public ArrayList<ListItem> getTi() {
        return listItemList;
    }

    public class Http extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() { super.onPreExecute(); }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
...
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
...
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: You have tons of ways of doing it. For me, the simplest one is just to add a listener reference to call after you finish the task.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use library [okHttp](http://square.github.io/okhttp/)

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

Request request = new Request.Builder()
                     .url(YOUR_URL)
                     .build();

client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call call, final Response response) throws IOException {
        if (!response.isSuccessful()) {
            throw new IOException("Unexpected code " + response);
        } else {
        // do something wih the result
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to see if it works, but if I wanted to set it as a method and pass a callback or a promise as an argument, how can I do?